# Symfony controller embedd error: The controller for URI "/_fragment" is not callable

Tags: symfony, controller, render

I'm calling a render like so in my Twig template (line 18)

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeReadingBundle:Default:newAction')) }}
```

And the controller is

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
    { 
      $message = new Message();
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($message)
        ->add('body', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

      $form->handleRequest($request);

      return $this->render('AcmeReadingBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

And the new.html.twig file is

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller for URI "/_fragment" is not callable.") in AcmeReadingBundle:Default:show.html.twig at line 18.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Solution:**

You're trying to render a **template** ( '...new.html.twig' ) using `controller()` instead of a **controller/action**!

change your `render` function to :

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeReadingBundle:Default:new')) }}
```

(*notice*: no "...Action" in method name)

---

**Tip:**

The _fragment exception is mostly thrown if there is something wrong with the controller name specified.

i.e. missspelling the controller/action name is often the reason for this exception.

---

**Further reading:**

Take a look at [this cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers).

Comment: sorry should be new instead of newAction

Comment: My controller is called newAction, as in the code sample. And I'm calling it like AcmeReadingBundle:Default:Action

Comment: Also beware of having two identically named controllers in different bundles and putting your action in the wrong one! In my case I had AdminBundle:Tag and ContentBundle:Tag, and I'd put my listAction in the AdminBundle's controller by mistake.

Comment: Another thing to take into account: Make sure your method name is `methodNameAction`, if the `Action` keyword is not present you are gonna get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @nifr
You're trying to render a template ( '...new.html.twig' ) using controller() instead of a controller/action!

change your render function to :

{{ render(controller('AcmeReadingBundle:Default:new')) }}

(notice: no "...Action" in method name)

> Below is more if above solution is not giving you solution.

1. Check if a defined function in the controller is a public function. In my case I have defined that protected.

Thanks,

Anirudh Sood.